# How to mock an aws lambda function call inside another lambda function with nodejs and mocha

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, aws-lambda, mocha.js, chai

I am writing unit test for a lambda function (exports.handler) with mocha and chai. There is another lambda function call inside the one which I am writing unit test.

I don't want to invoke actual call to the second lambda function. Are there any ways to mock the call to this lambda function?

```
exports.handler = (event, context, callback) => {   
try {
  var lambda = new AWS.Lambda();    

   /*need to mock this lambda call*/                

   lambda.invoke({
   FunctionName: myFunction,
   Payload: payload}, function(error, data) {});
}
catch(e){
}
```

Any helps are really appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

I agree with @AironBrynchke to use consistent approach. Since you already use `async/await`, let's avoid using callback.

This is how I do to test it.

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');

exports.handler = async (event) => 
{
    try
    {
       const lambda = new AWS.Lambda();    

       await lambda.invoke(
       {
           FunctionName: 'whatever', // I changed it for test sample
           Payload: 'payload'
       }).promise();
    }
    catch (ex)
    {
        console.error(ex);
    }
};
```

And for test

```
const chai = require('chai');
const sinon = require('sinon');
const assert = chai.assert;
const proxyrequire = require('proxyquire');

const invokeStub = sinon.stub().returns({
  promise: sinon.stub().resolves()
});

// here we want to mock `Lambda` 
const src = proxyrequire('path-to-your-source-file', {
  'aws-sdk': {
    Lambda: sinon.stub().returns({
      invoke: invokeStub
    })
  }
});

describe('lambda test', function() {
  it('runs test', async function() {    
    await src.handler({});

    assert(invokeStub.calledWith({ FunctionName: 'whatever', Payload: 'payload' }));
  })
});
```

Comment: Thanks all for your valuable replies. I did it using aws-sdk-mock. Even aws-sdk-mock is using sinon in background.

Comment: @IssacJohnson cool, never heard about aws-sdk-mock. Worth to check it out.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you are mixing two styles. If you are using **try** && **catch** block then:

```
exports.handler = async (event) => 
{
    try
    {
       const lambda = new AWS.Lambda();    

       await lambda.invoke(
       {
           FunctionName: myFunction,
           Payload: payload
       }).promise();
    }
    catch (ex)
    {
        console.error(ex);
    }
};
```

How to test your lambda function with mochaJs:
I can provide several references and you can figure out by yourself what is fit to you.

1. npm lib aws-lambda-mock-context (callbacks)
   ref: https://github.com/SamVerschueren/aws-lambda-mock-context
2. another npm package lambda-tester (callbacks)
   ref: https://www.npmjs.com/package/lambda-tester
3. And take a look at mocking-in-aws-lambda on stackoverflow
   ref: [Mocking in AWS Lambda](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36120984/mocking-in-aws-lambda)